# One word to describe a situation where two people have their first and last meeting in the same place

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions

There are two people who had their first date in a place. Six years later, they'll be meeting in that particular place for the last time because one of them is going to die. In the six year time period, there was a time when they loved each other but now there is just hatred between them.

They decide to meet there. But it's not for old times sake and not for some sentimental value attached to that place. They just wanted to meet over coffee and that happens to be the only coffee shop in their locality so they decide to meet there without giving it much thought. But while the girl is waiting for the guy she realizes that it's the same place where they had their first date (which was nice and sweet but now they only have bitter feelings between them).

I am not sure but I think I could have said that the situation was *poignant* if two lovers have their first and last date in a particular place. But these people are not lovers anymore. In fact either would be kind of happy if the other died.

Comment: Is it a Starbucks? That would be an important detail to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the word you're looking for is **irony**.

> While they waited for the waitress to bring their coffee, Cheryl suddenly realized it was in this very Starbucks where she and Andy had first met for coffee on that misty day in March six years earlier.  How ironic, she thought.

Answer (score 3):

*Poignant* could describe the situation as well, if it's:

> keenly distressing to the feelings
>   or
>   affecting or moving the emotions

([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poignant))

although *[bitter](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bitter?s=t)* or *[remorseful](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/remorse)* might describe her feelings better.

If you're looking for a more apathetic term, you could describe it as a *[fluke](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fluke?s=t)*.

(All linked definitions are Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

The adverb **full circle** is a single compound instead of a single word, but it describes your situation so perfectly that it deserves to be mentioned.

> **full circle** *(adverb)*: through a series of developments that lead back to the original source, position, or situation or to a complete reversal of the original position → usually used in the phrase *come full circle*

— [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full%20circle)

In your example, the once-lovers have come full circle, or their situation has come full circle.